# How do I point just the Website to another IP but keep the email to existing hosting? Is this correct?

Tags: dns-zone

How do I point just the Website to another IP but keep the email to existing hosting?

Website has to point to IP: `202.51.74.81`

Email has to point to: `202.63.240.138`

We use the following for checking email:

- webmail.domainname.com
- mail.domainname.com
- domainname.com/webmail

I have done the following. Will it work? If not what will? Thank you.

```
domainname.com. 14400   IN  A
202.51.74.81
 
domainname.com. 14400   IN  MX  
Priority: 0
Destination: domainname.com
 
mail.domainname.com.    14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
www.domainname.com. 14400   IN  CNAME   
domainname.com
 
ftp.domainname.com. 14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
domainname.com. 14400   IN  TXT 
v=spf1 ip4:202.63.240.138 +a +mx ~all
 
webmail.domainname.com. 14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
whm.domainname.com. 14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
cpcalendars.domainname.com. 14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
cpcontacts.domainname.com.  14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
cpanel.domainname.com.  14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
webdisk.domainname.com. 14400   IN  A   
202.63.240.138
 
default._domainkey.domainname.com.  14400   IN  TXT 
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArRVrbgxh+ltKuFjtpVtbcwUvhADG2z5Ylr4fjq4LM4TaXp7TEoeD2i0ymjIwsFKMkwji4LhTq7rgdLghSJKi0WJkSQi6bGV//oLQrIh6TVht99UrLBzj90dVZ8hIptIx+y7nPbpojMxJZCobJfbeZ/kF5WtgLMe30Zemb/zZgBZPkQoltMsc0ebyEh/G1nVoaJcPEieFIsflYsCKHqlxT0BW1W8cAOMEzLJWFelym+PyZ+077gEcWcX+dxzfSPH3CeX80Pb6Gifa6qfU3hn45cLbx/3/WrKgXqeOKxRhIVmg3IK4iSByD3OdwLb8qTWv1iuZw/D8aYsvOMC3S+UndwIDAQAB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably otherwise ok, but your `MX` record should point to the mail server!

```
example.com. IN MX 0 mail.example.com.
```

Comment: Thank you

So I have done this:



domainname.com.np. 14400 IN MX 
Priority: 0
Destination: mail.domainname.com.np

Comment: Yes, as that server handles your incoming mail.

Comment: We use this url for webmail: 
webmail.domainname.com.np.

So will that work too?

Comment: Everything pointing to the mail server is handled by it, so yes.

Comment: Thank you ... Bless you 
I will update you shortle with the progress

Comment: Thank you. .
This worked for me. 
Thank you..